# How to rename Read Groups

Tags: sam, read-mapping

I periodically run into problems with Read Groups. I am in a desperate need for a tool that would allow me to fix them.

This time, when I was mapping reads, I formatted all the information in the Read Groups right, but the name of the read groups (which I, unfortunately, chose to be RUN_LANE, not realizing that some of the samples were on the same lane in the same run). And once I tried to do a joint genotyping, freebayes got mad at me.

So, is there an easy way to rename read groups?

[Piccard tools' AddOrReplaceReadGroups](https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#AddOrReplaceReadGroups) won't do the job as some of the samples were multiplexed on different lanes/runs and this information should be preserved.

Basically, I need all bam files with read groups like this

```
@RG     ID:HJ5FNDSXY_L2 SM:WW5-6        PL:ILLUMINA     LB:WW5-6
@RG     ID:HJ5JVDSXY_L2 SM:WW5-6        PL:ILLUMINA     LB:WW5-6
@RG     ID:HJHGLDSXY_L4 SM:WW5-6        PL:ILLUMINA     LB:WW5-6
```

to change to something like (so the ID string will be unique for every combination of sample, run and library)

```
@RG     ID:WW5-6_HJ5FNDSXY_L2 SM:WW5-6        PL:ILLUMINA     LB:WW5-6
@RG     ID:WW5-6_HJ5JVDSXY_L2 SM:WW5-6        PL:ILLUMINA     LB:WW5-6
@RG     ID:WW5-6_HJHGLDSXY_L4 SM:WW5-6        PL:ILLUMINA     LB:WW5-6
```

There is a similar question asking about [adjustments of read groups using pysam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/5182/57). That is actually quite close to what I need, but it's rather hacky solution I would rather avoid if I can.

I also vaguely remember seeing a tool for fixing read groups problems while ago on Twitter, but I can not find it now and I don't know if I just made it up or not.

Comment: The most annoying part of this problem is that the lowest effort solution is to remap the reads with corrected RG IDs (but I always feel bad for burning computational hours in vein).